# How to create an array of 10 digits for counting repetitions?

Tags: python, arrays, list, flags, digits

I wondered how to create an array of 10 digits, such that each time a digit of a number shows, it increments its matching place in the 10 digits array, like this:

```
digits=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
num_digits=[1,2,3,9,1]
```

and digits becomes:

```
digits=[0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

I tried:

```
digits[num_digits[j]]=digits[num_digits[j]]+1
```

(j goes backwards on num_digits elements)
but I got the error "list indices must be integers, not list".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems `j` somehow is a list, not an integer.  Show the code defining `j`.

Comment: With this definition of `j`, [there is no error](http://ideone.com/KneYn).

Comment: defaultdict and Counter are the ways to go on this.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: I disagree.  [Progo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489986/279627) is concise, readable and much faster than any solution involving `defaultdict` or `Counter`.  There are also advantages to the latter, but with the informantion given in the question there is no way to conclude they are "the ways to go".

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Well, I'll half-agree with you. My knee-jerk response to just about any of the many "I'm trying to keep count of x's in y" questions here is either defaultdict or Counter. In this special case, where the values themselves work cleanly as list index values (the values 0-9), and there is a known small number of them (10), then using a list of 0's and keeping the tally by value is fast and simple.

Comment: @SvenMarnach:  But once the tallying is done, more work may be required for which defaultdict or Counter may provide additional support "out of the box", which the plain old list solution would have to replicate (keys(), items(), "in", etc). With the data stored in just a plain old list, there are no helpful access API's and you have to keep rolling your own. These are the "advantages of the latter" to which I think you were referring, and I think 9 times out of 10 make it worth it for the OP to learn Counter and defaultdict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> digits=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> num_digits=[1,2,3,9,1]
>>> for d in num_digits:
...     digits[d] += 1
... 
>>> digits
[0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

We wouldn't need a variable `j` for a simple iteration of a list.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth using a `dict` rather than a `list` to store your totals.  You could then use [`defaultdict` from `collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a `dict` which will automatically create a entry with a zero `int` for new keys:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> digits = defaultdict(int)
>>> num_digits = [1,2,3,9,1]
>>> for d in num_digits:
...     digits[d] += 1
... 
>>> digits
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 9: 1})
>>> digits[1]
2
>>> digits[8]
0
```

Comment: I'd definitely recommend this using a dictionary instead of a list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` for that task as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

num_digits=[1,2,3,9,1]
digits = [0]*10
for key, value in Counter(num_digits).items():
    digits[key] = value
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find how you could implement counting sort in python: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Counting_sort#Python

Comment: Not only does the example output in the question not match the results of a counting sort, you provided an external link instead of an answer to the question.